# DWORD is incompatible

Tags: visual-c++

I am working on hardware features in vc++.

I am working on to get this `siSysInfo.dwOemId` but `dword is incompatible` error is stopping me

I even tried `strcat(text,(char*)siSysInfo.dwOemId)` but no use.

Here is my code

```
SYSTEM_INFO siSysInfo;

GetSystemInfo(&siSysInfo);

char parent[1000] = {""};
char text[700] = {""};
char str[700] = {""};


strcat(text, "<b><font color=\"yellow\"> ");

strcat(text,(char*)siSysInfo.dwOemId);

strcat(text, str);
strcat(text, "</font></b>");

AddLOG_message(text, 0, 0);

#pragma MESSAGE("TODO: testing")
```

In console application its working as 
 printf("  OEM ID: %u\n", siSysInfo.dwOemId);

but in normal application --- strcat(text,(char*)siSysInfo.dwOemId);
is not working.

Comment: A dword is an integer and not applicable for strcat try sprintf or a conversion funtion to convert it to a string.

Comment: Please include in question an expected behavior. Are you trying to get platform (x86/x64/ia64/arm) or something else?

Comment: thanks for your kindly replies. yes am working on 64 bit PC. Is this issues an access violation problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes `word` is measure of amount of data bits that can be passed over system bus, AFAIK. Thus it can't be compatible since for 16bit platforms it will have 16 bit and for 64bit platforms it will have 64 bit.

And regarding that `strcat(text,(char*)siSysInfo.dwOemId)` I'm pretty sure that `dwOemId` doesn't have ending zero and thus requires using of `strncat(text, (char*)siSysInfo.dwOemId, sizeof(DWORD))` or something like that.

And looks like this isn't a string anyway. I suspect that you have followed [this sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but you should turn your look to the line `printf("  OEM ID: %u\n", siSysInfo.dwOemId)`. As you can see they use `%u` formatting (`unsigned int`).

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724958%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> dwOemId
>
> ```
> An obsolete member that is retained for compatibility.
> ```
>
> Applications should use the wProcessorArchitecture branch of the
>   union.

So that line might look like:

```
switch(siSysInfo.wProcessorArchitecture)
{
case PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64: strcat(text, "x64"); break;
case PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_ARM: strcat(text, "ARM"); break;
case PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_IA64: strcat(text, "ia64"); break;
case PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL: strcat(text, "x86"); break;
case PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_UNKNOWN: strcat(text, "unknown"); break;
default:
    /* code should be updated to include updates 
     * in wProcessorArchitecture enumeration */
    strcat(text, "unidentified"); break;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Solution:

SYSTEM_INFO siSysInfo;

GetSystemInfo(&siSysInfo);

use unsigned char instedof char.\n

follow the below example.

unsigned char text[700] = {""};

strcat(text,(char*)siSysInfo.dwOemId);

refer the below link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724423(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: What you wanted to say with `unsigned char text[700] = {""}`? You can write i `= ""` and `= {}` and you'll get the same behavior but it will be reasonable. Anyway `unsigned char` is like unsigned integer with same amount of bits as  `char`. Usually it is used for representing bytes. But `strcat` isn't applicable for the whole range of bytes (zero is treated as end of "string"). And sample refers to that field as `unsigned int` (see my answer and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)).

Comment: with the link, In console application its working as 
 printf("  OEM ID: %u\n", siSysInfo.dwOemId);

but in normal application --- strcat(text,(char*)siSysInfo.dwOemId);
is not working.

Comment: @user1858925, I guess you have some script background. For strong typed languages its natural to have different branches of handling for different types. In this case `strcat` works with `char *`, `printf("%u",...)` takes `unsigned int`. You should either convert `dwOemId` to string (simple reinterpretation of memory area isn't enough, you should form string from number) or you can use `sprintf(text + strlen(text), "%u", siSysInfo.dwOemId);` directly to get behavior you wanted (at least that's what I think). But you should consider the fact that `dwOemId` is deprecated (see my answer).